# WatchApp Submission to app store

Tags: watchkit, bitcode, watchos

Invalid Executable - The executable 'xx.app/Watch/watchkitapp.app/PlugIns/watchkitapp Extension.appex/watchkitapp Extension' does not contain bitcode.

Getting this error In watchkit extension build settings there is no option for bitcode. Please help.

Comment: I have got same error. Let me know if you have resolved.

Comment: facing same error, Looking out for solution

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar error when my app id's were not set up correctly. Make sure you have one for the iOS app, one for the watch app, and one for the watch extension (yes, the watch UI and extension require separate identifiers).